# Is there any way to style a shape file while rasterizing (converting to a .tif file) using gdal_rasterize command?

Tags: command, tiff, shapefile, qgis, geotiff

I want to add styles to my tif file which I am converting from a shape(.shp) file.
I am converting the shape file to a tif file using gdal_rasterize command.
I am not able to find a way to attach a qml style file to this command so that output tif file wil have the styles.
We can apply the styles using qgis but I want to apply the styles using terminal commands.

I tried to find a command which will allow me to attach a qml style file while converting the shape file to tiff file.
I also studied the parameters of gdal_rasterize command I didn't find any way to do that